# In what manner are AngularJS promises resolved?

Tags: angularjs

When a promise is resolved, does the code inside   `.then`   block get executed in a parallel way or the current execution stops and `then` block gets executed and it resumes again from that point where it had previously stopped?

Comment: I think its dependent on browser-specific JS implementations, but generally I believe async callbacks are parallelized in modern browsers (could be wrong). The important part is not the parallelization though - its the asynchronicity. Also, you can use different promise implementations (I presume you are talking about `$q`, which generally does this, but there are others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of `WebWorkers` JavaScript execution in the browser is a single thread.

It is neither that the callback is run in parallel or that the current execution is paused while the callback is run. The callback will run when the current execution is complete.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted to know. Can you provide any link or something where I can read more about it?